# Socket server no connection

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, connection

Hi I'm new to java socket and I've been trying to create a server socket. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong because I'm getting an error saying "Address already in use". Sometimes I don't get an error but instead it just doesn't form a connection. Help please? Here's the server class and the client class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MessageServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    int port = 8080;

    //int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);


    while(true){
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        Socket client = server.accept();

        System.out.println("Client from " + client.getInetAddress() + " connected.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client said: '"+inputLine+"'");
        Writer count = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        byte c [] = count.toString().getBytes();
        count.flush();


        }
}
```

}

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MessageSendClient {

public static void man(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Socket server1 = new Socket("143.210.72.82", 8080);
    System.out.println("Connected to " + server1.getInetAddress());
    InputStream in = server1.getInputStream();

    byte c[] = new byte[100];
    int num = in.read(c);
    String count = new String(c);

    System.out.println("Server said: " + count);
}
```

}

Comment: Try with "localhost" instead of `143.210.72.82` and don't use 8080 port no that is already used for other purpose.

Comment: Likely your program isn't closing the socket each time you run it and the socket becomes available only after the socket time out.

Comment: You have run server two times simultaneously.

Comment: Its working fine for me with `localhost`.

Comment: Could you tell me how run it only once please?

Comment: Please use @username to ask from specific person.

Comment: @Braj sorry about that, it's my first time im using this site lol

Comment: btw, does anyone understand the what this means "Resource leak: 'server' is never closed"?

Comment: @Braj can you please tell me how i have run the server twice??? I have done everything with no luck. I'm guess you're right and the issue must come from what you have suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are in Linux 8080 / 80 / 8443 are no good ports us an other port like 3456.
And always always Close your socket from your Client.

Update:
first of all, you should not Close the Server socket with Server.close(), Server should be running. and thats why the while Loops is there. you should Close your Client socket, with socket.close() after you have get the inputstream from Server. Remember also to always Close your outputstream with Close() after your write() and flush() to avoid side effect. Make two class, one for the Server and one for the Client. Start Java class Server first, and then run your Client class to connect to Server. terminate your Client class and run it again. if you are using eclipse, also terminate the Client in your console. sometimes the Java processes are overlaping, so just terminate all the running process with the x button. After you have improved your example codes, you can start Server and Client class again.
If it is still not working, you need to repost your question again and Show your current codes in Details for the Client and Server. somehow i have lost the track, where is your current state, cause you have already approved the answer to your question.

Comment: hey, I did just as you said, still no connection. It's still giving the "Address already in use" error

Comment: Are you running the Client main or the Server main in the same Shell? You should first start the Server main, and then start the Client main in an additional class call. Maybe try the example with two different PCs, just for sure you are calling the main correctly. And terminate all the active old Server and Client. Sometime you don't see the old Server on the same port are still running.

Comment: Yeah, earlier it was on the university computers and now on my laptop at home, still same issue :(

Comment: @voskart: maybe you should improve your answer.

Comment: @user3576868: i have updated my answer, take a look at the update section.

Comment: I've done everything you have said and still no luck. I will upload my code with the latest updates with a more helpful question..Could you check it out?

Comment: Just go ahead, it is what we are doing here in Stackoverflow, to make help. Please also post your error output from your IDE or terminal. Just as an advice, you can check the registed Ports from /etc/services (linux) or from C:\System32\drivers\etc\services (windows). I do appreciate your trust and the reputations. But you can also approve my answer, after it works for you. Basically i am interested in solving problem and better myself

Answer (score 0):

don't use your ip but use localhost or 127.0.0.1
and also try a new port, try to use a port greater than 1024 (most under this number are well known port and they're registred to IANA)

Comment: If there's a connection created, shouldn't there be a System.out.println("Client from " + client.getInetAddress() + " connected.");

..?

Answer (score 0):

Try a new port. I wouldn't use 8080 since it may be (and probably is already used). Also try to always close the socket after you used it.

Since I used sockets myself for university purposes, here is the code (if you need UDP or RMI I can post them as well)

```
public class TCPClient {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
      Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666);

      PrintWriter data_to_server = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader data_from_server =
              new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

      //Schicke Nachricht an Server
      BufferedReader system_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      long start_send = System.nanoTime();
      String msg = system_reader.readLine();
      data_to_server.println(msg);

      //Erhalte jeweilige Antwort
      msg = data_from_server.readLine();
      System.out.println("Data from Server : " + msg);
      System.out.println("Timespan: " + (System.nanoTime()-start_send));

      socket.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TCPServer tcp = new TCPServer();
        tcp.initialize(6666);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initialize(int port) throws IOException {
    // Erstellen eines Server Sockets
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

    while (true) {
        // Warten bis die Verbindung besteht
        System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect...");
        Socket socket = server.accept();

        // Writer für die ausgehende Antwort
        PrintWriter data_to_client = new PrintWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        // Reader für die ankommende Nachricht
        BufferedReader data_from_client = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        // IP-Adresse des Clients
        InetAddress remoteIp = socket.getInetAddress();

        // Erhalten der Nachricht
        String msg = data_from_client.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client " + remoteIp + " : " + msg);

        // Versenden der Antwort
        send(data_to_client, msg);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried changing this but im still finding it troublesome creating a connection. Do you understand the meaning of "Resource leak: 'server' is never closed"?

Comment: @user3576868 The only thing I can imagine is that you did not close the client-socket like I did for example (client_socket.close())

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I've tried to use server.close() on the client class and it still doesn't work. I still still get adress in use. Does that mean I have to change the port number again. Ive gone up 10000 now @voskart

Comment: you are using the following?

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);

and

    Socket client = new Socket ("127.0.0.1", 1234);

Then it should actually work

Comment: the server class is fine, that works but when i run the client class, then i get this error "Address already in use" evem after I've used the ip and port you've used..... :/

Comment: @user3576868 This is interesting...make sure you are binding to the correct IP-address and that you terminate the running sockets (I assume you use eclipse). If this still didn't work you could try and use netstat to check which ports are currently used.

Comment: I've tried using this to find available ports and i still got the same error

ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(53705);
   System.out.println("listening on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

Comment: Apparently i have run 2 servers simultaneously. Is that true?

Comment: @user3576868 Something rather funny may happen as well (since I've just tried it myself). If you have two separate tabs (classes) and start the server first and then just click on run again it may happen, that eclipse just tries to run the server one more time even though you wanted to run the client.

Comment: what do you think i should about that? someone said i run the server twice simultaneously and now I'm paranoid about it.

Comment: @user3576868 It should be impossible to run a service twice on the same port.

Comment: @user3576868 I just wrote a minimalistic TCP communication. Working for me, try it: [click](http://pastebin.com/vz2MzJHC)

Comment: @voskat I've tried running your code as it is and I get this error..

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind